# vuetify shows blank page on firefox after setup

Tags: firefox, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've follwed this tutorial setting up my vuetify project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbEW3xAmhKs

I did the follwing:
vue create vuetify-test -> I chose "manually" -> Babel, Router, linter -> history router (yes) -> Eslint only with error prevention

thats it. After that I ran "npm run serve" and when I click the localhost...-link I get a blank page. with the developer tools in firefox I can see that all tags are at the top in one line. What am I doing wrong??

//router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

    Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Need some code or snippet to figure out.

Comment: what do you need? I didn't add any line to the code. I added my router.js to the question